# How to make Ubuntu recognize Samsung galaxy battery level?

Tags: android, battery, gnome-power-manager

When I plug in an iPhone device, it automatically charges the battery, and showing battery's power percentage.

How to do so, with an Android device?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does Ubuntu battery display that it is suitable for Samsung? Generally speaking, the battery extender can be suitable for most models, like [iPhone extended battery](http://www.tabletpcphones.com/iphone-backup-battery) also fits for other phones. That's why smartphone app developers tout battery-conservation apps. These programs purport to save battery life by clamping down on unnecessary tasks, ensuring that your phone is running only the apps you really need at any given moment.